# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+]

Tags: android, react-native

I am constantly getting this error when I am upgrading my rn version from `0.66.2` to `0.68.2`.

**What went wrong**

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-os'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 16):

After some time of deep digging, I figured out that `react-native-os` is still not compatible with the new version for rn.

This is how I resolved the issue.

**Step 1** -> Go to `node_modules/react-native-os/android/build.gradle`

**Step 2** -> Under dependencies -> replace `compile` with `implementation`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
}
```

Comment: After doing this I get a new error: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [build_92f25wvfb7bvxtoudpxxnfpux$_run_closure3@44ba2fc9] on project ':react-native-os' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
I don't suppose you know the next thing I could try?

Comment: sorry, my error got resolved after doing the above step.

Comment: The thing with this solution is the moment you run yarn install the library is going to return to its previous state

Comment: Yes, that is correct. To resolve that you can add a patch for this package in your repo or you can fork the repo and make the change in your forked repo and use it. @JesusAlmaral-Hackaprende